# Meaning of the expression 'Handsome of'

Tags: formality, ielts

In my essays, I used to write,
"
...a **handsome of** amount is spend...", or "..earn a **handsome of** money as perks..."

But one of my online trainer, told me that to use 'handsome of' like this, is a wrong expression.. Can any, native English speaker or IELTS/PET trainers here, please comment on it?

Comment: You need a teacher/coach/trainer who will teach you how to consult standard references (print and online).

Answer (score 1):

**handsome**. [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/handsome)

In the sense of:

> - Appropriate or fitting: a handsome location for the new school.
> - Large in amount or measure; generous or considerable: a handsome reward; won by a handsome margin.

'Handsome of' in a sentence:  from the [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/38578?rskey=C4OlnU&result=1&isAdvanced=true#eid8693521)

> E. Burke Corr.   The Tories are very eager to congratulate. It was
> not **handsome of** them to condole on the ill-successes of last year.

and

> - and Seward himself wrote him a very handsome tribute.
> - She wasn't actually groveling in the dust,..but it was a handsome    apology.

Your stated usage of 'handsome of' is not grammatical.  Better would be:

... earn a handsome (amount, quantity etc) of money as perks

... a handsome amount is spent

Comment: Thanks @lbf for the clarification...